# Search recursively for a list of filenames in shell

Tags: bash, find, cat, cp

I have a list of file names inside filenames.txt like the following:

```
1.sql  
2.sql  
3.sql  
..  
..  
500.sql
```

I want to search for the file names in a directory and its sub-directories like the following:

```
Dir1/1.sql   
Dir1/2.sql   
Dir2/3.sql   
Dir3/4.sql   
Dir4/5.sql   
Dir4/6.sql   
..   
..   
etc
```

and copy the founded files to another directory.

I tried:

```
$ for i in `cat filenames.txt`; do `find ./* -type f -printf "%f\n"|grep -ie "$i" && cp -t "$i" /home/user/other_directory/"$i"`; done
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: What shell are you using - Bash? Can you expand on "doesn't work" at all? What does happen when you run this?

Comment: yes i'm using bash.. and what i mean by it doesn't work is it takes like 5 second and returns back to command line with no errors and when i check the new directory i find it empty

Answer (score 1):

because the first argument of cp is "$i" (the matching pattern) and not the filename

```
find . -type f -iname "$i" -exec cp -t "{}" /home/user/other_directory \;
```

Comment: it gives "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: the last argument of find command `\;` (literal semicolon) is important

Comment: i took it copy and past.. and it when i put it after the cat output to complete the idea, it gives me a new line with the sign >  as it needs another argument.